# Concatenate time as text in Excel but ignore blank values

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have several columns I am trying to join in Excel, including a date and time.  All of the rows have dates but a lot of the time values are blank.

At the moment I have the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(B2,"dd mmm yy "), TEXT(C2,"[h]:mm"))
```

This works fine when I have a date and time (eg 13 Nov 16 10:50) but if the time column is a blank value I get a result as midnight (eg 13 Nov 16 0:00).

How can I ignore blank values so that the result displays (13 Nov 16)?

Comment: include a if statement for empty cells, if empty do nothing, if date do your text

Answer (score 1):

Apply empty check on cell value.

Update formula would look like -

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",TEXT(B2,"dd mmm yy ")), IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",TEXT(C2,"[h]:mm")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Place an IF around the formula:

```
=IF(C2<>"",CONCATENATE(TEXT(B2,"dd mmm yy "),TEXT(C2,"[h]:mm")),TEXT(B2,"dd mmm yy"))
```